# TFS 2012 not detecting deleted files in pending changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

We have multiple developers on our team.  This works for everyone except one developer, but we cannot seem to find the reason it does not work for this individual.  We all have VS premium+, TFS 2012 power tools installed.

We have a branch.  We get latest version from branch.  Go to windows explorer and delete all files in folder "sdk" (there exist no subdirectories in sdk/).  Then we copy into it a bunch of files.  (This effectively leaves some files as new files, updated files, identical files or removed files when compared with what was deleted.)

When we go to pending changes, these changes show up under "Excluded Changes - Add(s) 51, Deletes(3)".

Except for one developer.  His system does not recognize these changes.  What might cause this to not work for him?

If it helps troubleshoot, he is also the only developer that if he were to delete these files via power tools delete option in windows explorer, his .dll files get locked.  This does not happen for anyone else either.

This is what we've checked so far:

[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]
[image: Settings]

EDIT:  Solution Found - Thank you all for the responses!  It was indeed the local vs server workspace option.  Setting his workspace to local solved these and a few other issue he was apparently having.

Comment: how do you see that "His system does not recognize these changes"

Comment: in the Pending Changes window, under Included Changes there is a menu called View Options. Can you check that this is set to Show All? if this is set to Show Solution Changes it hides all changes not in this solution

Comment: And you confirmed that he uses a "local workspace" as you guys use?

Comment: I'm with @Isaiah4110 - this is almost certainly a server workspace.  Convert it to a local workspace and see if it doesn't behave like yours.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, you should post it as an answer and accept it!

Comment: Edward: Yeah, I never know what is acceptable to do on SO when the answer comes in as a comment from someone else.  So, I just +1'd everyone that contributed toward the solution.  I'd feel awkward posting the answer when @Isaiah4110 and then you were the first to answer with the solution I was able to use.

Comment: For the sake of others visiting this post, I have put a small write up about the local vs server workspaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the developer is using a "Local Workspace" as opposed to the "Server Workspace".

This is a concept which was introduced in TFS 2012 which helps developers to work offline as opposed to server workspace in earlier versions which did not allow that. TFS 2012 changes up the workspace options. Server workspaces are still available, and work exactly has they have in previous versions. However, TFS 2012 now contains a new type of workspace, called a Local workspace. Again, this is an oversimplification, but in a Local workspace, all the files are read/write, not read-only. The meta-data about the files is stored in a hidden folder in the root of the workspace, which allows edits, renames and deletes to be done locally without any communication to the server.

This improves the offline story with TFS significantly, as you no longer encounter issues with editing read-only files. It also makes it easier to work with other tools (such as Notepad) to edit code files. Making a change to a code file using Notepad will still mark that file as edited, which will be picked up by TFS the next time you connect.

[LINK](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx)

Comment: Great! Changing my workspace to Local instead of Server made edits done outside of Visual Studio (notepad/vs code) to automatically show up as pending. Saved a lot of pain :)

Answer (score 1):

This only ever happens when a user tampers with a local view of source control (be it a local workspace, or not). If all you ever did was get latest from TFS this would never occur, instead, the local view of what is in TFS would always be properly managed.

Also sounds like a bad merge, e.g. getting latest (where the files no longer exist) then copying in old content (introducing untracked files.) One thing you might try doing to correct the issue is doing a forced fetch from TFS after deleting the local workspace contents BEFORE attempting a merge. This will ensure that the local workspace is up to date an accurate with what the TFS server believes is truth, if it still occurs after merging in content then the problem is almost certainly within the merge process the user is going through (i.e. PEBKAC, or a knowledge gap about what they are doing.)

If you unshelve old content (pre-deletion) into the local workspace (where the deletions have already been performed, according to the SCC, and thus locally because of a sync/get-latest) then the unshelved files will effectively become untracked and it's up to the user to clean up the mess. This is identical to a user having copied loose files into their workspace that TFS never had any knowledge of. TFS isn't going to prune untracked files for you, I believe some other source control tools might do this as a configurable default, TFS does not.

That this is only happening to one developer in the team suggests that the other developers, one at a time, should sit with this developer and drive using "their process" to see if it still occurs for them. More often than not this comes down to a bad process a user has adopted, and putting a different person in the chair can help highlight why it has been occurring and help end it. A disciplined build/source manager and/or developer should not experience this problem.

Very interested in knowing what the problem turns out to be.

Comment: In particular, this isn't the right way to update sdk contents: "Go to windows explorer and delete all files in folder "sdk" (there exist no subdirectories in sdk/). Then we copy into it a bunch of files."

The appropriate method would be to delete SDK from within VSTUDIO, commit the change, then add a new SDK folder. Alternatively, you would want to identify each removed file and delete it from within VSTUDIO.

Deleting and updating files this way (from Windows Explorer) results in a desync between what is on disk, and what TFS/VSTUDIO believes is the correct state.

Comment: Right.  That's why local workspaces do this scan and pend the appropriate changes, so that you can go make changes in windows explorer (or any other tool) at your leisure and have them pended appropriately.